# How can I get MonoLog's ErrorHandler to output to stdout?

Tags: php, shell, stdout, monolog

I am a bit confused about using MongoLog to send logs to stdout. I am using this code:

```
# console/proxy-server.php
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\ErrorLogHandler;

// This is for test - it *definitely* goes to stdout!
echo "Hello";

// Here is the logger
$logger = new Logger('stdout');
$logger->pushHandler(new ErrorLogHandler());
$logger->info('Logging');
```

The log line does indeed output to the console where I run the program, but it seems it is not going to a real stdout. However, the "Hello" from the `echo` works fine.

I am launching it from a shell script thus:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Write to both stdout and a log file
php console/proxy-server.php | tee --append proxy.log
```

If I use `tail -f proxy.log` in another console then the `echo` message pops in real-time, but the logs I am interested in do not (even if I exit the script cleanly, though I would expect them to append in real-time too). However, both sets of outputs *are* output to the console in which I have run my script.

This implementation approach [was sourced from this blog article](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/logging-to-stdout-with-monolog).

### Update

In the blog article comments there is an alternative solution using `StreamHandler`, which is thus. It's the same as above except for a changed `pushHandler()` line:

```
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

...

$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler("php://stdout"));
```

This *is* recorded by `tee`, so it looks like some stdouts are more equal than others! I wonder if there are effectively many stdouts, and `tee` only records the "real" one? What is the difference between the two approaches, in terms of shell pipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, as my alternative solution works fine with `tee`. However, of late I suspect that `ErrorLogHandler` in fact sends output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, which would be why `tee` does not render it.

If anyone else bumps into this, I should be interested in their observations. In some ways it's an edge-case, since in most cases error output is rendered to the console just in the same way as non-error output, and one cannot normally tell the difference.